# Is there something similar to 'rake routes' in django?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, routes, django-urls

In rails, on can show the active routes with rake (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
$ rake routes
          users GET  /users          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
formatted_users GET  /users.:format  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
                POST /users          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
                POST /users.:format  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
```

Is there a similar tool/command for django showing the e.g. the URL pattern, the name of the pattern (if any) and the associated function in the views?

Comment: Another good way is if you are in debug mode you can put a bogus url like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1234` and it will show you the url patterns

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Have found https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions:

```
$ ./manage.py show_urls
```

Answer (score 5):

An experiment ...

```
# appended to root urls.py

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
    from django.utils.termcolors import colorize
    import os, sys

    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ialtr.settings'

    def traverse(url_patterns, prefix=''):
        for p in url_patterns:
            if isinstance(p, RegexURLPattern):
                composed = '%s%s' % (prefix, p.regex.pattern)
                composed = composed.replace('/^', '/')
                print colorize('\t%s' % (composed), fg='green'), '==> ',
                try:
                    sys.stdout.write(colorize('%s.' % p.callback.__module__,
                        fg='yellow'))
                    print p.callback.func_name
                except:
                    print p.callback.__class__.__name__
            if isinstance(p, RegexURLResolver):
                traverse(p.url_patterns, prefix=p.regex.pattern)

    traverse(urlpatterns)
```

Now, if one runs `python urls.py` ...

```
$ python urls.py
    ^users/activate/complete/$ ==> django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template
    ^users/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ ==> registration.views.activate
    ^users/register/$ ==> registration.views.register
    ^users/register/complete/$ ==> django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template
    ^users/register/closed/$ ==> django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template
    ^login/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.MethodDecoratorAdaptor
    ^logout/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.logout
    ^password/change/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.MethodDecoratorAdaptor
    ^password/change/done/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done
    ^password/reset/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.MethodDecoratorAdaptor
    ^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm
    ^password/reset/complete/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete
    ^password/reset/done/$ ==> django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done
    ^ialt/applications/$ ==> ialt.views.applications
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$ ==> django.views.static.serve
    ^$ ==> django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template
    ^about/ ==> django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template
```

Answer (score 4):

When I tried [miku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094270/4794), I got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

It looks like the problem comes from using `django.contrib.admin.autodiscover()` in my `urls.py`, so I can either comment that out, or load Django properly before dumping the URL's. Of course if I want to see the admin URL's in the mapping, I can't comment them out.

The way I found was to create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) that dumps the urls.

```
# install this file in mysite/myapp/management/commands/urldump.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from kive import urls


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Dumps all URL's."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.show_urls(urls.urlpatterns)

    def show_urls(self, urllist, depth=0):
        for entry in urllist:
            print ' '.join(("  " * depth, entry.regex.pattern,
                            entry.callback and entry.callback.__module__ or '',
                            entry.callback and entry.callback.func_name or ''))
            if hasattr(entry, 'url_patterns'):
                self.show_urls(entry.url_patterns, depth + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[admindocs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#using-the-built-in-reference) has a similar feature. But it doesn't display URL names.